# Line pay integration with android app

Tags: android, integration, payment-gateway

I want to integrate line pay (payment gateway) in my android app. My app will be used in Thailand so line pay is client's requirement. I read merchant doc but no information found about android integration.
Please help me if anyone knows about it.